# teleop_controllers package in electric

Tags: ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Was the teleop_controllers package (http://www.ros.org/wiki/teleop_controllers) moved in electric or is there a plan to release it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11117/teleop_controllers-package-in-electric/) by [Sarah Osentoski](https://answers.ros.org/users/701/sarah-osentoski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 136 on 2011-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've think I've figured this out.  The JTTeleop controller is now located in robot_mechanism_controllers and it shows up in the controller manager as robot_mechanism_controllers/JTCartesianController.

---

Originally posted by [Sarah Osentoski](https://answers.ros.org/users/701/sarah-osentoski/) with karma: 136 on 2011-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1